# objective-c: Using NSManagedObject for saving data with CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is it possible to extend an derived class from NSManagedObject? I'm asking this because I tried to do it. My entity looks like this:
[image: entity]

So this means a class similar to the following code should be generated:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber* orderNumber;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@dynamic name, orderNumber;

@end
```

This two variables are saved to the SQLite database.

Now since I need some additional variables for the player I just added them to the class. It still worked.

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@dynamic name, orderNumber;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self reset];
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize isStillInGame = _isStillInGame;

- (void) reset
{
    _isStillInGame = TRUE;
}

- (void) setOutOfGame
{
    _isStillInGame = FALSE;
}

@end
```

But now when I change the `isStillInGame` bool, all instances of the Player Class are changed. Is this normal or do I have an error in my code?

A second question I can't answer is, why I can't access the object variables while debugging. When I try to watch an Player instance variable I just see this:
[image: debugging]

Is it possible to see more?

Comment: you can type `po [players objectAtIndex: someIndex]`

Comment: then I get: `<Player: 0x8e56b80> (entity: Player; id: 0x8e56670 <x-coredata://EC155238-53B1-4F10-B3FD-6026D38A8152/Player/p1> ; data: <fault>)` What does this mean?

Comment: What version are you using? Usually on the top right corner there was a small eye icon, that would show the values.

Comment: well that is the description of the object, which is all faulted the core data engineers didn't want description to fault in data, if you need to know a specific value you can do things like `p (int) [players objectAtIndex: someIndex].someIntProperty`

Comment: okay, it looks like the bool variable just changes in execution. Is it in objective-c still possible to write over the datatype's memory?